# kubernetes 1.2 to 1.3 upgrade on CoreOS

Tags: kubernetes

There seem to be several issues to go from 1.2 to 1.3 that makes it impossible to upgrade in place.

Is this correct?

When upgrading one worker node to 1.3.4, while the rest is running 1.2.2, the node is never `ready`

I get lots of 415 errors (unsupported media type?) from kubelet, which seems to indicate incompatible format.

`kubelet[2927]: E0804 01:55:13.794921    2927 event.go:198] Server rejected event '&api.Event{TypeMeta:unversioned.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:api.ObjectMeta{Name:".146777d057f9b62b", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:0, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*unversioned.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]api.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil)}, InvolvedObject:api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"198.245.63.87", UID:"xxxxxxxx", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"NodeHasSufficientDisk", Message:"Node xxxxxxxx status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk", Source:api.EventSource{Component:"kubelet", Host:"xxxxxxxxxx"}, FirstTimestamp:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63605872340, nsec:72642091, loc:(*time.Location)(0x45be3e0)}}, LastTimestamp:unversioned.Time{Time:time.Time{sec:63605872513, nsec:790683013, loc:(*time.Location)(0x45be3e0)}}, Count:29, Type:"Normal"}': 'the server responded with the status code 415 but did not return more information (post events)' (will not retry!)`

I'd like to understand if it's a setup issue or a real breaking change that prevent in-place upgrade...

Thanks

Comment: Did you update your API Server first? You should always do so.

Comment: updating api server first doesn't sound like a good idea, as if it fails it's the whole cluster that is threatens, so i'm hoping updating a minion at a time is a reasonnable approach, but obviously it's kot this easy.

Comment: Your API Server can't understand what your components are saying if it has a lower version. Only the API Server guarantees backward compatibility with other components. If you're afraid of downtimes you should deploy a multi master cluster. It's also worth mentioning that your cluster keeps functioning while the master is down, node components will just stop receiving updates generated by the scheduler and controller manager, in most setup this gives you enough time to figure out what's wrong while keeping all pods online.

Answer (score 1):

I've done an upgrade of 1.2.2 to 1.3.3 on CoreOS. This involved first upgrading the master server, then doing the nodes....

All went surprisingly smoothly...

Basically I followed:
https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-upgrade.html